# Merge failed: Merge request is not mergeable. Please try again

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

Our Merge request has been merged successfully, But it shows below message in the merge request.  Is it something bug in our Gitlab CE Version- 12.4.3? `production.log`also have the same message.

```
[root@gitlab-server gitlab-rails]# cat production.log |grep -a "Merge request is not mergeable"
MergeService ERROR: gitlab/remidey!27 - Merge request is not mergeable
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be error. I request you to logout and login once and also check from Admin login so that he can have access to make any workaround here. I suggest to raise a issue here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues

Comment: Same message even shown in admin login as well. Sure will raise ticket in provided GitLab Support link.